# R quantmod chart_Series: switching off the RHS y axis label for add_TA(as indicators close together overwrite scale)

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to switch off the right hand side y axis label.
The reason I am trying to do this is that if you have a few indicators close together then the RHS scale gets overwritten.

I can do this by altering myTheme

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY", from="2013-01-01", to=Sys.Date())


myTheme <- chart_theme()
myTheme$rylab <- FALSE

chart_Series(SPY,theme=myTheme)
```

But when I add an indicator it reappears again

```
add_TA(SMA(SPY[,4],20),on=1,col="black",lty=2, lwd = 1,legend = NULL)
```

How can I switch the RHS y axis for indicators?
Also how can I make the y axis on the LHS have larger fonts?

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2):

[Edited] You repeat the application of  `theme=myTheme` after `add_TA(...)`

```
myPars <-chart_pars(); myPars$cex<-1.5
cspy <- chart_Series(SPY,theme=myTheme, pars=myPars)
cspy <- add_TA(SMA(SPY[,4],20),on=1,col="black",lty=2, lwd = 1,legend = NULL)
cspy
cspy<- chart_Series(SPY,theme=myTheme, pars=myPars)
cspy
```

Note that you will need to use again the margin widening strategy I showed you yesterday because the default margins are insufficient on the LHS.

Comment: I tried: add_TA(SMA(SPY[,4],20),on=1,col="black",lty=2, lwd = 1,theme=myTheme) but it did not seem to work.Warning message:"theme" is not a graphical parameter

Comment: Yeah. I was reading the chart_Series help page after typing ?add_TA and thinking it applied.

Comment: Unfortunately the penultimate line seems to remove the indicator line.

Comment: Curse. Foiled again. Not quite as object-oriented as I thought.